# visualising data with python of time series and float colmn

Tags: python, dataframe

i have the following quastion-
What can you tell about the relationship between time and speed? Is there a best time of day to connect? Has it changed throughout the years?
this is my dataframe[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgfsR.png)

[my columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHwix.png)
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg6XE.png)

does any one have any suggestion on how i would aprouch this question ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/dimagoroh/Desktop/data_vis/big_file.csv', low_memory=False)
sns.lmplot(x="hours",y="speed",data=df)
```

im trying to do a plot but get this error i think i need to manipulate the hour column to a diffrent data type right now it is set as object

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the error you get. From the data I think you need to pass `x="hour"` and not `x="hours"`. Also try

```
df.hour = pd.to_datetime(df.hour)
```

Comment: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32') , yes I changed it to hour

Comment: Create a new column as ```df['hour_numeric']= df.hour.timestamp()``` and use this as the x variable. I think the problem is caused because you are trying to create a linear model with an object as the x variable and not a numeric variable.